# Passing a parameter to an ionic angular service

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to write up a button to display in ionic based on some condition that I want to evaluate in a service. I need to  let the service know who called it. So I want to send a parameter to the service. But I see that whatever parameter I pass from my template html, the variable is not visible in the service. Sample code below.

```js
   
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.service('testService', function TestService() {
  return {
    testFunc: function(param) {
      console.log("Hello"); //This prints correctly
      console.log(param); //This prints as undefined
      if (param == 1) return false;
      else
        return true;
    }
  }
})

.controller('testController', ['testService',
  function(testService) {
    console.log("Hello world");
    testService.testFunc();
  }
])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>

  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  <!-- your app's js -->
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="testController">

  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <button class="button button-full button-positive icon ion-thumbsup" ng-if="testService.testFunc(10)">&nbsp;Test</button>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Has anyone come across this situation and what is the way to get it working?

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made two mistakes or missunderstood how to use a service in your html code.

Inside your controller you already call a service function with `testService.testFunc()`. And because you don't pass a parameter here you wan't receive some paramter in your service.

```
.controller('testController', ['testService', function(testService) {
    console.log("Hello world");
    testService.testFunc();   
}])
```

In your html code the following line calls the function `testService.testFunc(10)`. The problem is, your $scope doesn't know such a function. The result will be `ng-if="undefined"`. Your service will be never called.

```
<button ng-if="testService.testFunc(10)">&nbsp;Test</button>
```

***So, there are two easy solution get this works.***

You can add the service to your `$scope` with

```
.controller('testController', function($scope, testService) {
    console.log("Hello world");
    $scope.testService = testService;  
})
```

or you define a new `$scope` function inside your controller and call the service inside this function.

```
$scope.myFunc = function(param){
   return testService.testFunc(param);
}
```

and

```
<button ng-if="myFunc(10)">&nbsp;Test</button>
```

Comment: $scope needs to be injected, see my answer from an hour earlier

Comment: In my first example the service is injected and in the second there is no need to do so...

Comment: Ohh... I see what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.controller('testController', ['$scope', 'testService',
  function($scope, testService) {
    console.log("Hello world");
    $scope.testService = testService;
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It does work from within controller. I have tested that. But i need to get it working with ng-if. I am also trying to use it within ion-tabs and the ion-tab parent is usually an abstract state so I cannot assign a controller there.

Comment: I am not "making it work" inside controller, I am assigning it to the scope, so your html can "see" it...

Comment: at worse, if you have no controller (gasp) assign it to `$rootScope`

Comment: have you tried my suggested modification? Did it work?

Comment: The first answer is the right answer and I have marked it so. The way I was trying to get it work originally, doesnt work at all as the function in the service can not be called, unless done via a controller.

Comment: It's the same and I wrote it first :)